# Field Value change not being saved

Tags: c#, sitecore, editing

I am trying to change a field value dynamically from back-end, but looks like the changes are not being saved.

**Code**

`item` is fetched from the master database.

```
   using (new EditContext(item))
   {
        item.Editing.BeginEdit();
        try
        {
            //Value is updated here from "" to Test
            item.Fields["Content"].Value = "Test";
        }
        finally
        {
            //item.Fields["Content"].Value is "" again. 
            item.Editing.AcceptChanges();
            item.Editing.EndEdit();
        }                 
    }
```

**UPDATE**

As @sitecore climber said, I did change my code back to use -

`new  Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler()`

However, the issue was caching. The updated value was displayed in the content editor, only after I had cleared the cache and restarted the browser.

To get around that, I disabled caching before making the edit and turned it back on once the editing was done.

```
CacheManager.Enabled = false;

       using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler())
       {
            item.Editing.BeginEdit();
            try
            {
                item.Fields["Content"].Value = "Test";
            }
            finally
            {
                item.Editing.EndEdit();
            }                 
        }
CacheManager.Enabled = true;
```

Comment: Are the changes committed to the database you expect? Try switching to either Web/Master to see if the changes are there.

Comment: I am trying to make changes to the master database only. Switching doesn't work either.

Comment: Have you tried to put everything in the try {} or test without the try/finally all-together? Maybe those scopes mess something up.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Disabling cache doesn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add : (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler())

EditContext containts next lines of code :

```
 public EditContext(Item item)
{
  Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) item, "item");
  this._item = item;
  this._item.Editing.BeginEdit();
}
```

so you don't need here if you have in your code 
    item.Editing.BeginEdit();

your code must be :

```
  using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler())
 {
    item.Editing.BeginEdit();
    try
    {
        //Value is updated here from "" to Test
        item.Fields["Content"].Value = "Test";
    }
    finally
    {
        //item.Fields["Content"].Value is "" again. 
       // Remove AcceptChanges I never use it , for editing . 
      //  item.Editing.AcceptChanges();
        item.Editing.EndEdit();
    }                 
}
```

I updated my answer, did you check on content editor if are any changes ?
Can you clear cache, and check again. It's really strange why is not working I guess can be a caching problem .

Comment: I forgot to add that I had actually tried that too. And, it didn't work either. It loses the value on AcceptChanges() or EndEdit().

Comment: You were right about the cache. When I cleared the cache and restarted the site, I could see the updated value in the content editor. Any idea of how I can force the value to be updating in the CE without clearing the cache?

Comment: I actually got it working by disabling caching before doing the edit and then enabling it once it was done. Thanks.

Comment: @NomadTraveler How did you disable the cache during the edit?

Comment: @MikkelNielsen I had updated my question with the working solution. Check the 'UPDATE' section

Answer (score 0):

Try using SecurityDisabler if it helps..

```
 using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler())
{
  item.Editing.BeginEdit();
    try
    {
        //Value is updated here from "" to Test
        item.Fields["Content"].Value = "Test";
    }
    finally
    {
        //item.Fields["Content"].Value is "" again. 
        item.Editing.AcceptChanges();
        item.Editing.EndEdit();
    }
}
```